# Erlang, Syntax error before using a guard

Tags: syntax, erlang

```
map_search_pred(Map,Pred) where is_map(Map)-> map_search_pred(maps:to_list(Map), Pred);
map_search_pred([H|Tail], Pred) -> 
    case Pred(H) of
        true -> H;
        false -> map_search_pred(Tail, Pred)
    end;
map_search_pred([], Pred) -> {error, Pred}.
```

I'm having a syntax error before "where" line 7 which is line 1 in this code. I am not sure why this is thrown however I am still a beginner in erlang so I might've missed something on my way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guard sequence beginning with the keyword `when` not `where`,

```
Name(Pattern11,...,Pattern1N) [when GuardSeq1] ->
    Body1;
...;
Name(PatternK1,...,PatternKN) [when GuardSeqK] ->
    BodyK.
```

`where` should be replace by `when` in the code

```
map_search_pred(Map,Pred) when is_map(Map)-> map_search_pred(maps:to_list(Map), Pred);
map_search_pred([H|Tail], Pred) -> 
    case Pred(H) of
        true -> H;
        false -> map_search_pred(Tail, Pred)
    end;
map_search_pred([], Pred) -> {error, Pred}.
```